# sqlalchemy with Typeerror but pyodbc works

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have tried multiple ways to connect to MSSQL with sql alchemy but always get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-100-71745b407575>", line 1, in <module>
    conn = engine.connect()
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2473, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 878, in __init__
    self.__connection = connection or engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2559, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.unique_connection()
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 184, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy(self).checkout()
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 401, in __init__
    rec = self._connection_record = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 746, in _do_get
    con = self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 189, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 287, in __init__
    exec_once(self.connection, self)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event.py", line 377, in exec_once
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event.py", line 386, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 168, in first_connect
    dialect.initialize(c)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc.py", line 135, in initialize
    super(PyODBCConnector, self).initialize(connection)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 1164, in initialize
    super(MSDialect, self).initialize(connection)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 177, in initialize
    self._get_default_schema_name(connection)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 1180, in _get_default_schema_name
    user_name = connection.scalar("SELECT user_name() as user_name;")
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1383, in scalar
    return self.execute(object, *multiparams, **params).scalar()
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1449, in execute
    params)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1628, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1691, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\wantai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 333, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

Here is my code

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pyodbc
engine =sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://uid:pwd@AWS1DNA01/xxx_Database,driver = SQL+Server')
conn = engine.connect()
```

In addition, I have tried to pass through the parameters as suggested by the documentation and got the same error.

```
conn_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={SQL Server}; Server=AWS1DNA01; Database=xxx_Database; Integrated Security=False;UID=uid;PWD=pwd")
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(conn_string))
conn = engine.connect()
```

What does this error mean and how do i fix it?
Also, I have tried to use pyodbc to connect and it works:

```
conn_string = "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=AWS1DNA01; Database=xxx_Database; Integrated Security=False;UID=uid;PWD=pwd"
connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
```

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: probably [this sqlalchemy docs entry](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string) may help

Comment: @IljaEverilä I have added the full traceback. Hower, I can't format it as code as stackoverflow thinks i have too much code.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Hi Azat, I have tried the pass through approach and it has returned the same error.

Comment: have you tried to interpolate parameters into URL string like in the docs?

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy and pyodbc are you using?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov yes. i have tried it. I have included the code in the question.

Comment: @IljaEverilä pyodbc 4.0.27, sqlalchemy 1.3.9

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that your question is not showing us what you are actually doing. `mssql+pyodbc://uid:pwd@AWS1DNA01/xxx_Database,driver = SQL+Server` is not a valid connection URI; it would fail with "Data source name not found and no default driver specified". The URI would need to be `mssql+pyodbc://uid:pwd@AWS1DNA01/xxx_Database?driver=SQL+Server`. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed the issue, although I still don't know the cause of the original issue. Instead of using pyodbc, I used pymssql to create the engine and it works.

```
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://uid:pdw@server/db?')
```